# How to access position of an array of struct using pointer

Tags: c, struct

Answer (see below): When accessing a struct with a pointer, one needs to use the arrow operator "myStruct->structVariable" which is the equivalent to "(*myStruct).structVariable" which is called dereferencing a pointer (getting the value instead of the address). When accessing the struct directly one uses "myStruct.structVariable".

I'm pretty new to C and pointers and am trying to do the following:
I'd like to access an array of structs which is part of another struct. The struct is a pointer which gets passed to a function, in which i would like to access it.

Student has an array of structs which 10 Lectures (also a struct). To simplify the process of adding lectures to a student, i would like to be able to call the function "addLectureToStudent()" and passing the necessary arguments and assign the values to the array of lectures.

```
typedef struct Lectures {
  char name[20];
 
} Lecture;


typedef struct Students {
  char name[20];
  Lecture lectures[10];

} Student;     

void addLectureToStudent(Student * stud, int position, char lecture_name[20]){
    strcpy(stud->lectures[position]->name, lecture_name); //This line doesn't work as expected
}
int main(void) {

    Student markus;
    strcpy(markus.name, "Markus");
    markus.matrikelnummer = 12089548;
    addLectureToStudent(&markus, 0, "Programming");
}
```

My problem is, that when wanting to access `strcpy(stud->lectures[postition]->name, lecture_name)` it tells me that stud should be a pointer but isn't (thats the best translation i can come up with. It is originally in german..). How do i access the array of lectures properly in this case?

Comment: Your arguments in definition and invokation of `addLectureToStudent` don't match.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks, i forgot to delete them.

Comment: `stud->lectures[position]->name` how is this correct?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It isn't - i didn't know.. i personally would have done "stud.lectures[0].name" because i didn't understand the arrow operator but ("luckily") my IDE know better c code than i do...which is somewhat helpfull i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stud->lectures[position]` is `Lecture`, so you should use `.`, not `->`, to access that.

```
strcpy(stud->lectures[position].name, lecture_name);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I obviously don't quite understand the difference between the two then. Will accept soon!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to access the structure elements, usng a pointer to a structure.

1. Using dereference operator and dot (`*` and `.`)

   `strcpy((*stud).lectures[position].name, lecture_name);`
2. Using arrow (`->`)

   `strcpy(stud->lectures[position].name, lecture_name);`
3. `markus.matrikelnummer = 12089548;`  This is wrong, because there is no element `matrikelnummer` in structure `Student`.
4. General syntax is `pointer_name->variable_name`  and `(*pointer_name).variable_name`

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice explanation! 
Oh yeah, sorry about the matrikelnummer. That's a German word so I took it out of the struct and obviously forgot to get rid of it in main...